# My application is returning the same location no matter where I am

Tags: java, android, location

So I want my app to track the location of the phone. I'm using a FusedLocationProviderClient to get the location. A person clicks a button, and then my app runs a trackLocation() function. My function, however, is returning the same longitude and latitude no matter where I am. Here's trackLocation:

```
 private void trackLocation(){
    button.setText("Tracking");
    fusedLocationClient= LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                MainActivity.this,
                new String [] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                1
        );
    }
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            double latitude=location.getLatitude();
            double longitude=location.getLongitude();
            TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
            String latText=Double.toString(latitude);
            String longText=Double.toString(longitude);
            textView.setText(latText+" "+longText);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to call  

    requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest request, PendingIntent callbackIntent)

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) for more details.

Comment: I called that but it still is just returning the same location regardless of where I am.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the location updates. You need to call this function to get the updates regularly. Set the interval by your preference.

```
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setInterval(20 * 1000);
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        if (locationResult == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            if (location != null) {
                wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }
};
```